# Is there any way for a wizard to speed up the casting time of the Planar Binding spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, spellcasting

We are preparing for a boss rush against the Demon Lords, and I am hoping to use [*planar binding*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/planar-binding) on one of them. However, that spell has a casting time of 1 hour, so I am wondering whether there are any items, spells, or methods to decrease that to an action.

We can bring any item with a rarity below legendary, and any wizard spell (except for wish because we failed the 33% chance) with us. We have two wizards: a Chronurgist and a Necromancer.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: You both lost the ability to cast *wish*?

Comment: And by “below legendary” you mean “very rare and below”?

Comment: this whole thing would be a whole lot easier with Wish, and wouldn't even risk triggering the 33% chance xD

Comment: All three of you failed your wishes?

Comment: Yeah I mean very rare and below, we didn't fail our saves but rather our DM gave us three flat uses of wish, and we weren't expecting to play these characters again. For plot reasons however we are doing a one shot that does require them though

Comment: @Scoopypoopy can you ask your DM to allow you to roll 33% normally, then?

Answer (score 2):

A little frame challenge - your DM probably should allow you to roll a chance to use Wish.

Per [your comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/191987/is-there-anyway-for-a-wizard-to-speed-up-the-casting-time-of-the-planar-binding#comment518519_191987):

> we didn't fail our saves but rather our DM gave us three flat uses of wish, and we weren't expecting to play these characters again. For plot reasons however we are doing a one shot that does require them though

3 flat uses are decent deal for one-shot characters, but not so great for recurring ones, so when you agreed to that, you didn't have information to make an *informed* decision. In other words, your *player's agency* was limited.

If your characters have never cast Wish in stress inducing manner, they should by all means be able to do it again. Even if some uses was stressful, each character's chance to still be able to cast it is, depending on number of stress inducing uses:

1. 67%
2. 67%<sup>2</sup> ≈ 45%
3. 67%<sup>3</sup> ≈ 30%

I strongly recommend you to ask your DM to allow you to roll that probability. That way you will be back to normal rules, and in worst case scenario you both used wish in stress inducing manner 3 times, you still have a 64% chance that at least one of you will be able to cast it again.

Comment: if your math is for probability to pass the 33% you need 1-.33^3.

Comment: @TigerGuy there is a 33% chance to never be able to use Wish again. So there is a 67% chance to be able to cast wish again. Chance to be able to use it after second casting is 67% of there being second casting * 67% of stress after second casting. Thus, my math is good.

Comment: across 3 characters the chance of passing at least once is much better than 33%.

Comment: @TigerGuy Question states there are 2 wizards, not 3, and my answer states there is a 64% chance o at least one still being able to cast wish, not 33%. So what are you really commenting about? Where are your numbers from? Especially that 33%, definitely *not* taken from my answer.